# What does File.exists? do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, standard-library

So I was looking through the Ruby standard library docs on how to read a file when I found [`File.exists?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-exists-3F), with this fascinating and illuminating description:

> ### exists?(p1)

(A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=file.exists%3F+ruby) turns up a similar amount of information)

It's a real method, as verified by attempting to call it and not getting an error. Based on a couple of quick tests, it seems to do the same thing as `File.exist?`.

Is this correct, or does it have some other behavior that I missed?

Also, as a side-question, why isn't it documented at all? Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ruby 2.2.0 doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-exists-3F), this method is deprecated:

> **exists?(file_name)** → `true` or `false`
>
> Deprecated method. Don’t use.

Comment: ...Where did you get this? I looked everywhere for something like this and couldn't find it.

Comment: ...Huh. I guess I was looking at 2.1.0 or below, then. Thanks for the help! EDIT: Yep, I was looking at 2.1.0, where it's just blank.

Comment: yes, if you ruby version >= 2.1.0, don't use this method.